# Could not find package javax.xml.bind in JDK 1.5

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-5

I want to use JAXB with Java5. I found this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html, so I presume that is compatibile with Java5, but when I try to look for this class in Eclipse I can't find it.

[image: This is a screen of my workspace]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

In java 5 you have to add `javax.xml.bind.jar`. it is not in the standard JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Added 2 dependecies to my POM file and all works fine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref: [Does JAXB work under Java 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895777/does-jaxb-work-under-java-5)

Comment: if use this version with java 1.5.got `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:547)`